# CLI way to repeat a command

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to execute a command, run for 20 hours, kill it, wait 5 seconds and repeat.

Example:

Is there a way I can accomplish this from CLI?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried.

Comment: A shell script is your friend, here.

Comment: I was looking for a CLI one-liner, no bash scripts etc

Comment: then replace the newline characters with `;`s.

Answer (score 4):

With `timeout` from GNU Coreutils:

```
while : ; do 
  timeout 20h yourcommand 
  sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this function?

```
run_command () {
    local command=($@)
    "${command[@]}" &
    local pid=$!
    sleep 72000
    kill -15 "$pid"
    sleep 5
    run_command "${command[@]}"
}
```

Once sourced you can run like:

```
$ run_command some_command
```

Comment: A loop would be much better than infinite recursion.